# Is there a closed form of $ \displaystyle \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}{\frac{\phi^{xk}}{k!_F}}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-series, closed-form-expressions, fibonacci-numbers

where $\phi = \frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}$ and $k!_F$ is the fibonorial of $k$, or the [product of the first $k$ Fibonacci numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonorial)? My hunch is that, this can be represented as a function in terms of the constant in the case where x=1, so I tried the following:
$$ 
\begin{split} S = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}{\frac{\phi^k}{k!_F}} & =\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}{\frac{F_k\phi+F_{k-1}}{k!_F}} \\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\Bigg (\phi\frac{F_{k}}{k!_F}+\frac{F_{k-1}}{k!_F}\Bigg)\\
& =\phi \displaystyle \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{F_{k}}{k!_F}+\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{F_{k-1}}{k!_F}
\end{split}
$$
How should I continue from here?. I'm asking for a closed form expression but any alternate representations as an integral or another series are greatly appreciated as well.

(Fibonacci numbers as defined by the recurence  $ F_k = F_{k-1}+ F_{k-2} $ and $ F_0=F_1=1 $)

(Edit: The first couple of terms of $ \displaystyle  \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(k-2)!_F}\frac{1}{F_k} $ and the first term of $ \displaystyle  \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(k-1)!_F} $  aren't defined so I changed it back to $ \displaystyle \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{F_{k-1}}{k!_F} $ and $ \displaystyle \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{F_{k}}{k!_F}$ respectively )

(Edit: It seems that $\displaystyle \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{F_k}{k!_F} = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k!_F}$)

Comment: I think it is always a good idea to give your definition of Fibonacci numbers: There are two natural indexations: $F_0=0,F_1=1$ or $F_0=F_1=1$. I guess you want the second one.

Comment: Thank you Roland, edited. @RolandBacher

Comment: I guess that something is missing: The title suggests a function. Then a constant $S$ is defined which becomes later a function.

Comment: Oh S is a constant and the case where x=1 of the function in the title, i thought that was clear. I don't see where S becomes a function though. @RolandBacher

Comment: The first term in the last summation is ${1\over(-2)!_F}{1\over F_0}$, and I'm having trouble seeing what $(-2)!_F$ could mean. If you start at $k=2$, you get a rapidly converging series, so you could compute a few decimals and then see whether you can conjecture a closed form for the result.

Comment: Thank you for that observation Gerry. I'm not sure how that can be defined (even a quick analytic continuation of the fibonorial diverges at -2 https://www.desmos.com/calculator/2c0zgh6lll ). Maybe that q factorial connection mentioned in the wikipedia page might define it but I tried and still can't get something. No accurate numerical conjectures using wolfram alpha either. Don't have mathematica so there may be some out there. (Excuse the wait, I just woke up). @GerryMyerson

Comment: Oh wait, that sum is equivalent to $\displaystyle \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{F_{k-1}}{k!_F}$ and $F_{-1}=1$ @GerryMyerson

Comment: It's not equivalent, because it has terms that don't make sense. I think you have to split of the terms with $k=0$ and $k=1$.

Comment: Right, but me simplifying $ \displaystyle \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{F_{k-1}}{k!_F}$ to $ \displaystyle \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(k-2)!_F}\frac{1}{F_k} $ was probably a mistake. @GerryMyerson

Comment: Edited, thanks. @GerryMyerson

Comment: $\sum_0{F_k\over k!_F}=1+\sum_1{F_k\over k!_F}=1+\sum_1{1\over(k-1)!_F}=1+\sum_0{1\over k!_F}$.